LWC Get Data From Descendants - Events vs Public API
In the Call Methods on Child Components documentation, it says:

To communicate up the containment hierarchy, fire an event in a child
component and handle it in an owner or container component. See
Communicate with Events.

However, on that same page it talks about defining a method on a child that can be called from a parent and return a value to the caller.
In the case of Grandparent > Parent > grandchild, where the data we want is captured in the JS controller of the grandchild - other than event bubbling, is there any other benefit to using Events versus calling a public API on the parent that calls another public API on the grandchild which returns data up the tree on demand?
Is there a performance consideration here, or is it purely a "best practice" scenario?
Code Example:
grandChild.js
@api get results(){
  return `helloWorld`;
}

parent.js
@api get childResults(){
  return this.template.querySelector('c-grand-child').results;
}

grandParent.js
handleOnSave(){
  const grandChildResults = this.template.querySelector(c-parent).childResults;
}


To have the child call the parent (and grandparent) suggests having to explicitly make the child aware of its parent (and grandparent). This increases component coupling, reduces reuse and is a bad idea. Events are generic and make it such that the parent (which already knows about the child, since the child is referenced in its template) is aware of the child, not the other way round.

Hey @PhilW, I think you misinterpreted my question, not sure if that's the fault of my description or not - I am not trying to communicate up by calling from child to parent. I am talking about exposing an API method in the grandchild & child which can then be called directly from the grandparent. I'll add some code to my question for clarity

@PhilW I added a code example - is there any reason why this approach is less performant or still more tightly coupled versus a bubbled Event?

OK, so calling API function from the (grand)parent down. This still introduces increased coupling (the grandparent now knows about the grandchild - though not necessarily, depending on structure; your example side-steps that except in naming). Also, with events you are notified at the time the change happens. Without events, the (grand)parent doesn't know when to invoke that API function.

There's no reason why you can't do this from a technical perspective. This has approximately the same performance. That said, the design intent of Web Components (not just LWC, but Web Components in general) is provide the ability to create reusable components. Further, there's the SOLID principles of programming. You can agree or disagree with them in general, but they do make some sense, and your proposal breaks a number of them.
By doing this, you introduce two problems. First, if you change the internal implementation of the grandchild, you may also force the parent and/or grandparent to also have to change. In other words, you're setting up additional future maintenance problems for no reason. Second, the component becomes less reusable, because using the grandchild component in other parent/grandparent components can multiply your maintenance work in the future.
So, while you can do this, consider not doing this, because it paints you into a corner that may be difficult to get out of. Even if you don't think you'll need to reuse the component, there's no way to guarantee this is true. By following standard principles, you reduce the risk that you need to do additional work in the future.

To know which of these two strategies adopt, you should answer a simple question: who (or where) starts the action?

If it is started by a child component, you should raise an event to notify whoever is up through the DOM. This way who added a listener for that event will be able to handle it asap.
Can this scenario be handled via public method? Yes, but polling until a change happens is really a bad idea and you should not follow this path if you can easily dispatch an event. Moreover in the case of Grandparent > Parent > grandchild, the Grandparent cannot access the grandchild, so it would be worse.
If it is started by the parent component, the only to notify a child is via public property/method.

This way you maximise the reusability of your components. Indeed almost every standard component could provide an example for the first case, i.e. if you have a reusable component whose only scope is display data in a specific way, like the lightning-datatable, and it let the user select something, dispatching an event to notify a parent component about what has been selected is the way to go.
What if the parent has another child and, once it handles the event, need to notify the second child? Now calling a public method exposed by the second child makes sense.
Even if grandParent doesn't need to handle the new data asap and may wait, so even if there is no polling, calling public methods isn't wise due to the reason stated by Phil and Sfdcfox.
So about your scenario, if the data are hold by grandChild and when it changes them the grandParent must be notified, the grandChild should dispatch an event.
If the event is created setting composed: true (the default is false) and if it isn't handled and stopped by the parent, it will reach the grandChild since composed events can break shadow boundaries, anyway using this configuration is an anti-pattern. The parent should handle the event and dispatch a new one.
Last note: if you're passing non-primitive data, please clone them before adding those data to the detail property. This way no one could alter the internal state of your component.
